# In PyCharm, variables in f-string come with green run buttons

Tags: python, pycharm, string-formatting, f-string

I am using PyCharm 2018.1.3 (Edu). Each variables used in an f-string adds a green run button in the gutter. Couldn't figure out why.
[image: Click here for screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried pressing one seeing as you've said they're buttons

Comment: f-strings are runnable code; they're not normal constants (the placeholders are filled in at runtime). It would make sense to allow "running" them so you can determine the final value. I don't use PyCharm, but surely you can just try running it and seeing what happens?

Comment: Hovering the mouse pointer over the "buttons" shows "Execute <module_name>". Clicking on them does nothing.

Comment: It seems to be a bug, I created a ticket in PyCharm EDU issue tracker: [EDU-1532](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/EDU-1532).

Comment: @ Pavel Karateev: Thank you. Btw aside from their unusual location of appearance, those green buttons don't seem to be causing any functional issue.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be happening any more.